# acc and cost is not stable in my CNN model

Tags: python, tensorflow, conv-neural-network

I have my own 6600 training image sets of digits(0~9), 18200 training image sets of lower English letters(a~z), 18200 training image sets of upper English letters(A~Z).

I first trained my digit training set with CNN model, and it worked well.

here is my CNN model formation.

```
learning rate = 0.0001

28X28 input image
11X11 output label.(0~9(5500 training sets) and none digit ex)a~z, A~Z(1100 training sets))

CONV1
filter(3,3,1,32)->relu->maxpool(1,2,2,1) and stride(1,2,2,1)

CONV2
filter(3,3,32,64)->relu->maxpool(1,2,2,1) and stride(1,2,2,1)

CONV3
filter(3,3,64,128)->relu->maxpool(1,2,2,1) and stride(1,2,2,1)->reshape(-1, 128*4*4)

FC1   
input - (128*4*4)   
relu    
output - (625)   

FC2   
input - (625)   
relu   
output - (11)  

its acc : 
![enter image description here][1]

its cost : ![enter image description here][2]
```

I think this CNN model trained well.

I trained same CNN model with my own English low letters(a~z), the problem was occurred.

There is just one difference with digit CNN model, that is FC2 layers output(27)

Here is acc and cost of CNN model trained with english low letters

acc : [image]

cost : [image]

there are serious fluctuating situation of acc and cost as compared with digit CNN model

I want to make this CNN model more stable. if you interest, would you give me some advice?

I think CNN model formation is the reason but can't explain what the problem is concretely

Answer (score 0):

Personally I think that the fluctuations on the English lowercase letters (a-z) looks normal to me. Comparing to the digits dataset, the fluctuations is most likely caused by the increase in number of classes present in your dataset. The digits dataset only has 10 classes, but the English lowercase letters has 26 classes. Hence it is logical that there is more fluctuations during the training of English lowercase letters dataset as the model is more likely to come across with example that it has not seen before.

One method you can try is to decrease the fluctuations is to increase the batch size so that the model can adjust its weights while "looking" at more examples at each training step.

Not too confident in my answer but this is what I observed throughout my 1+ year on training CNNs. Looking forward to see if it works on your model as well.

Comment: i changed batch size from 100 to 300 and printed logs of cost and acc on terminal after each steps, there is no fluctuations. but there is fluctuations on tensorboard scalar graph(acc and cost). i dont know why it happens, could you explain this situation?

Comment: I am assuming your question is about "why is there a difference between printed value and tensorboard value".

Perhaps the first thing you should check is there's no mistake with your `name` and `name_scope` variables. If there's no mistake, post another question and pm me the URL then I'll have a look at it :)

If my answer is correct, please mark it as correct. Thank you very much.